# Are "watch" and "look on" interchangeable in this context?

Tags: word-choice, difference

> Tina and Mary watch/look on as the reporter does a live report.

Hi. Are "watch" and "look on" interchangeable in this sentence?

Comment: Yes, they are pretty much interchangeable. _Watch_ has more of a sense of it being deliberate, while _looking on_ could be the action of bystanders who just happen to see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

> Tina and Mary **watch** as the reporter does a live report.

Most likely this means that Tina and Mary are watching TV.

> Tina and Mary **look on** as the reporter does a live report.

This means that Tina and Mary are at the location of the reporter doing the live report. You wouldn't use this one when watching TV.